# How can I display a modal with info from a scanned QR code?

Tags: react-native, expo

Tech stack: Expo, React-Native
Using: expo-barcode-scanner

I am trying to create an app that will scan a QR code and then display the info from the QR code on the screen, preferably in a modal so I can display an image.

I've created an app that will do that... except that it uses an alert function to show the text. How can I change it to a modal? When I try to change it to modal, or return a modal it doesn't work.

My code:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button, Modal } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';
import {createCustomerInformation2} from './src/graphql/mutations'

import logo from './assets/icon.png';
import Scanner from './components/QRScanner';
import custModal from './components/custInfo'


export default function App() {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  // const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    var newData = JSON.parse(data)
    // return(
    //   <View>
    //   <Modal>
    //     <View>
    //       <Text>Test</Text>
    //     </View>
    //   </Modal>
    //   </View>
    // )
    alert(`
      Customer: ${newData.name}
      Email: ${newData.email}
      Phone: ${newData.phone}
      Favorite Drink: ${newData.favoriteDrink}
    `);
    // createCustomerInformation2(newData)();
  };

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }



  return (
    <View id="view" style={styles.container}>
    <BarCodeScanner
      onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
      style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
      // If you want to use the front facing or rear facing, include type={'front'} or put 'back'
    />
    {scanned && <Button title={'Tap to Scan Again'} onPress={() => setScanned(false)} />}
    
  </View>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent: 'center',
},
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning that JSX in the onBarCodeScanned handler, you'll need to include it in the returned JSX of your App. You'll want to conditionally hide the modal when no value is present. You'll then populate it by assigning the scanned value to a state variable in the event handler and displaying that value in the modal.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what I need to do? The onBarCodeScanned came from expo's boiler plate code. Should I delete that whole line and just add that to a modal that I hide until after the scan? How would it populate the data?

Comment: Yeah, all you really need is `const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => { setBarCode({type, data}); setModalVisible(true); }` and then your modal could be something like `{modalVisible && <Modal><Text>{barCode.type} {barCode.data}</Text></Modal>}`

Comment: That is working. However, my var newData = JSON.parse(data) from the handleBarCodeScanned function needs to be displayed in my model. I cannot display the data if I put handlebarCodeScanned.data in the {} in the middle like you said. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, just parse it in the handler before calling `setBarCode`, then

Comment: There is no setBarCode. It was handleBarCodeScanned. I parsed it in the handleBarCodeScanned function because that is where I get the data. I parsed it immediately. However, I cannot find the data.

Comment: Ok, to clarify: you need to add another state variable: `const [barCode, setBarCode] = useState(null);`. This is where you will set the data in `handleBarCodeScanned` after parsing the JSON

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much!